# Wrong favicon on error page when trying to convert a deleted answer into a comment

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, russian-stackoverflow, favicon, convert-to-comment

If you are trying to convert a deleted answer into a comment, you will be redirected to error page.

> [image: Wrong favicon on error page]

As you can see, this page shows SOen favicon, but should use SOru icon.